# how to find data in previous date range in laravel

Tags: laravel, eloquent

hellow I want to get the logic to find the previous data in date range

Example we fetch data `from 2020-04-01 to 2020-05-02`, so want to get the data from previous this range

anyone can help the logic from here

this query is just return the data of date range, but not previous

```
       public function stock_by_period(Request $request){
                   $from = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($request->from);
                  $to = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($request->to)

                 $data=Loading::whereBetween('reservation_from', [$from, $to])->get();

                   dd($data);
             }
```

anyone can help me on this

Comment: what do you mean by the previous date range?

Comment: I can't understand `previous data in date range`. What's means?

Comment: @DilipHirapara  example like if you find the data for `today` that mean previous is data for `yesterday`

Comment: Do you want previous year, month or date ?

Comment: For you, current range is `2020-04-01 to 2020-05-02` then what is previous range? previous year?

Comment: @B_CooperA,,, No what i mean is previous from that range you selected 

example a week is from date 1 to date 2 so the previous date is last week , so how can i archive the previous data when you select by period ?

Comment: @DilipHirapara i thought like this `2020-03-31 to 2020-05-01` something like am not sure if am right or wrong that why am asking is it possible ? to get the previous range date?

Comment: Just update your question. Write Currently date range and date range you want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 public function stock_by_period(Request $request){
      $from = date('Y-m-d', strtotime("-1 day", strtotime($request->from));
      $to = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($request->to)

      $data=Loading::whereBetween('reservation_from', [$from, $to])->get();
      dd($data);
 }
```

Comment: thank for your answer, but why on `$to` we are not `-1 day` can you explain brother

Comment: If you want to change your date with previous date, -1 day for this